# How to navigate in a website using cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

I need to navigate in a website for send data in a web service.

First, i need to login in : http.://192.168.1.1/event/users/sign_in
Then, i will redirect a another page that is: http.://192.168.1.1/event
Finally, i need to go another page that is: http.://192.168.1.1/event/management/attendee
In this page, i need to send some data in array by method POST.

I post my code but don't work.

```
/* For login */
$userpwd = "root:root";
$curl_rsc = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_URL, $url_login);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, HTTP_AUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd); //Here i have some doubts. Because if i change this variable always have a http_code = 200.
// or i need to send data in a array for login?
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($curl_rsc); // Get a http_code = 200

/* For go to the redirect page */
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_URL, $url_next);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_exec($curl_rsc); //Get a http_code = 200

/* For go to the target url when i want to send data */
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_URL, $url_target);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attendee); //Send the data in a array
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl_rsc, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_exec($curl_rsc); // Get a http_code = 500 Internal Server Error.
```

Can anyone tell me what is my error? Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

> Here i have some doubts. Because if i change this variable always have a http_code = 200.

Are you using HTTP authentication? If not this is the wrong thing to do. Other than that, your script on the last page is failing so you need to check your server error logs to find out what's going on; there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code.

Comment: well, the webservice don't have some authentication... maybe, i confused the login that i view when i enter to the site.
However.. have the same error (500) .. where i can view the error if i don't have access to logs in web service?

Comment: What I mean by HTTP authentication is the box that the browser displays when you visit the page in which you must put your username and password, like the screenshot on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149337/http-authentication-in-net). If this is not the case and you have to login through the page itself then you will need to pass your credentials as either `GET` or `POST` parameters to the login page then possibly keep track of the cookies as well (I'm not sure whether curl does this automatically).

Comment: If you don't have access to the web service then you can't view the errors. You will just have to try and match what your script does with what the browser does when it accesses the page and hope it works.

Comment: Yes, this is my case.. is the box that the browser display when i visit the page with the url of login. So, i update the code with additional line. Is ok? or Not?

Comment: `CURLAUTH_ANY` would be better so it just uses whatever authentication method is available.

Comment: Try using Wireshark to compare what you are sending when you request the last page to what a browser sends when doing the same thing.

Comment: don't work.. It's weird because always get a http_code=200 when i login by cURL. I asked if the webservice have a authentification, but they said me the don't have. I don't know what is the problem. Always fail in the last 2 lines.